# Search parse.com data form html input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, parse-platform

I can get data from a specific parse object using the following:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="searchnumber" id="searchnumber" value="" placeholder="Customer Number"/>  
<button type="submit" id="search" data theme="a">Search</button>
```

JS

```
var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
retrieve.get("xQz2oXkrq5", {  
    success: function(retrieve)  
        {  
        var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
        var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber");
```

I want to be able to search for a particular entry using the number entered in the HTML search box, rather than having a hardcoded ObjectID as is shown in the JS. Any ideas how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for an existing object based on the customer name or number by using a [Parse.Query](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-basic).

```
var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
var query = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);
query.equalTo("customername", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // results is an array of CustomerObjects
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " customers.");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cheers,
the fix for my example was:

var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);    
retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val());    
retrieve.first({    
success: function(retrieve)

Comment: @Hector Ramos - I don't actually think you answered the original posters question did you?