# Replicating code to search parse using text input box returns console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm trying to extract the answer in the comment from this question. I have the code as shown below so far, but I cannot understand how to remove the

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

error being returned in Chrome console. Can someone explain how to resolve this? Also is it possible to get a Chrome plugin that helps trap/explain errors like this further?

[Search parse.com data form html input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238928/search-parse-com-data-form-html-input)

```
var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val()); 
        retrieve.first({ success: function(retrieve) 


    }
        var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
        var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber");
```

Comment: You are missing a `{ and }` after the function. Just look at the code for the selected answer...

Comment: @epascarello as per the update now made to the question?

Comment: If you add this as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer, or people looking at it will not understand what the issue was. I've rolled back your question to the code that needed fixing so the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code.

```
var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val()); 
        retrieve.first({ success: function(retrieve) 
        {

        }

    });
        var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
        var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber");
```

Comment: I would suggest that the two lines that use the `retrieve` (badly named) value from the success handler should be inside the function block. Possibly rename the success parameter to `retrieveResults` so as not to confuse things.